# Game function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For this function,showGame, and the expected output, anyone can give me a hand to make this work ?

```
import System.IO  

type Symbol = Int  

showGame :: [Symbol] => IO ()  
showGame xs =   
    let x = mapM_ (replicate '*') xs  
    putStrLn x
```

The output should be:

```
1: *  
2: **  
3: ***
```

with

```
 [Symbol] = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Functions named `show` in Haskell typically provide a `String` rather than an IO action. You might want to name this `printGame` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing a few mistakes in your code we get this:

```
type Symbol = Int  

showGame :: [Symbol] -> IO ()  
showGame xs =
  mapM_ (\x -> putStrLn $ show x ++ ": " ++ replicate x '*') xs

main = showGame [1..3]
```

Output:

```
1: *
2: **
3: ***
```

Comment: This is also a good place to use `forM` (`mapM` with the arguments flipped) because then it reads like a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
let x = fmap (flip replicate $ '*') [1,2,3]
mapM_ putStrLn x
```

`mapM_` applies a monadic action over a list but discards the results. This is what you want to print, since there is no useful result. However you do want the a result when creating the lists to display. Here you can just use `fmap` (or `map` since the input is a list) to create a list for each input list element.

Comment: I'd say `(\`replicate\` '*')` is significantly more readable than the equivalent with `flip`, and in fact easier to understand (though it actually uses more advanced features of the language).